# how to fix html-pdf node module arbitrary file read vulnerability?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I want to convert html to pdf document. Using html-pdf npm module, which contain vulnerability.
https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-HTMLPDF-467248

Please suggest the alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is json to pdf. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit which is very popular. You would have to convert your existing templates from html to json but it works.

Also you can just provide the phantomjs argument using the config

```
phantomArgs: ['--local-url-access=false']
```

[Full details](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/530)